# MVC 5 login custom DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm switching from mvc 3 to mvc 5, I know they changed the authentication in .Net 4.5.1 (OWIN authentication).

all I need it to log in the website so the Request.IsAuthenticated is true, I don't want the membership of Microsoft, I want to use my database.

What I tried is not working even this

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name"));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "mail@mail.com"));
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

var ctx = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
```

I really don't know what to do but I want to be logged in the system using my own database, the has only username and password

Comment: I am pretty sure Forms Authentication will continue working.

Comment: Sorry, but when i use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie it didn't make the Request.IsAuthenticated true

Comment: Do you have <authentication mode="Forms"> in your web.config?

Comment: i do have it in my web.config
is there is anyway that i can use this new authentication?

Comment: Well you can implement your own provider but I believe it should be possible to run FormsAuthentication with MVC5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I hope it will help you.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = MyViewModels.checkUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user!=null)
            {
                SignInAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    private void SignInAsync()
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "UserName"));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "User@mail.com"));
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Welcome()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If you add [Authorize] attribute in the action, then it will redirect only the user name and password is authorize

Function to get user name and password from database

```
    public static UserTable checkUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        DemoEntities db = new DemoEntities();
        var query = (from u in db.UserTables
                     where u.UserName == userName && u.Password == password
                     select u).FirstOrDefault();
        if(query!=null)
            return query;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post to see how set up a bare bones OWIN authentication with your own membership system.

[MVC 5 Forms Auth](http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux)

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't help